# Earn the average of a row in a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that returns the average of some column like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Financial] 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        avg([aa ]) as 'aaa',
        avg([bb]) as 'bbb',
        avg([cc ]) as 'ccc',
        avg([dd]) as 'ddd',
        avg([ee]) as 'eee',
        avg([ ff]) as 'fff'
    FROM [FIN]
END
```

NOW my problem is that I want to have the average of this procedure's result, I mean this current procedure give me a row that it contains average of some column. Now I want to have the average of this row! what can I do?

Let me explain more the result of above procedure may be:

```
4,7,8,9,6
```

For next I want the average of

```
4,7,8,9,6
```

Comment: As a note, you might want to use a table-valued function or view rather than a stored procedure.  This would allow you to use the results directly in another query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling NULL values is something of a pain.  If all the values in a column can be NULL, the following will calculate the average:

```
SELECT aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff,
    ((coalesce(aaa, 0) + coalesce(bbb, 0) + coalesce(ccc, 0) + coalesce(ddd, 0) +
      coalesce(eee, 0) + coalesce(fff, 0)) /
     ((case when aaa is null then 0.0 else 1.0 end) +
      (case when bbb is null then 0.0 else 1.0 end) +
      (case when ccc is null then 0.0 else 1.0 end) +
      (case when ddd is null then 0.0 else 1.0 end) +
      (case when eee is null then 0.0 else 1.0 end) +
      (case when fff is null then 0.0 else 1.0 end)
     )
    ) AS Average
FROM (
    SELECT 
        avg([aa ]) as 'aaa',
        avg([bb]) as 'bbb',
        avg([cc ]) as 'ccc',
        avg([dd]) as 'ddd',
        avg([ee]) as 'eee',
        avg([ ff]) as 'fff'
    FROM [FIN]
) AS Averages
```

Comment: +1 - This is much better than mine is; I had too many assumptions about NULL values.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables :( I told ya, when I put this:SELECT aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee, fff,     ((coalesce(aaa, 0) + coalesce(bbb, 0),... sql dosen't know aaa and bbb and... anymore:(

Comment: @Sara . . . when I run the above code preceded by `with fin as (select 1 as [aa ], 2 as [bb], 2.5 as [cc ], 3 as [dd], 4 as [ee], 5 as [ ff])`, it works.  Is it working for you?